# If there a way to add a rivets.js attribute with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr, rivets.js

I have a bootstrap table of "delivered items". The table is using rivets.js to bind all the JSON to it. Each row has a table description, a shipped quantity and an input box for the received quantity. There is a rivets attribute that I want to add when a specific event happens.

Event: Users can choose to "show mismatches", which means that the table filters out all table rows that have a shipped quantity that is not equal to the received quantity and I want the event to happen through jQuery.

I have tried:

```
$(".show-mismatches").click(function () {
    $(".table-items").each(function (i, x) {
        $(x).find("td").attr("rv-if", "item.sqty | neq item.rqty");
    })
})
```

This is what I see when I inspect the element
[image: This is what I see when I '']

The attribute is added but is not doing what it should.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: If I'm reading the rivets documentation correctly, it looks like `rv-if` is a templating tag that would be used by rivets during its generating of elements.  That's not something jQuery would be able to change after the fact.  By the time the elements are in the DOM, rivets has already generated them from the template(s).

Comment: I would suggest the more appropriate way to address this would be to create a click event listener with rivets (however they do that), that changes a variable in the associated `item` object that would result in the mismatches being shown

Comment: So, initially after the click event happens, all the table cells get the attribute, but don't hide. After I test the code out by adding a received quantity that is the same as the shipped quantity, then the attribute hides everything that it is supposed to. Its almost like it needs an event after the event that adds the attribute to the rows for the rows to actually hide.